# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost...' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have a .net core app which has a REST API being used by an angular client but running into CORS issue.

In the .net core, I already have

```
app.UseCors();
```

in the configure method as well as has set the response headers to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

but still getting the error in the client (running on port 4200 locally):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/myAPI/api/Table' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 1):

Pass-through for preflight requests:

```
if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
     return;
    }
```

Also Read this: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Not sure where that would go? in the asp.net core code?

Comment: in the method that is receiving the request.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add cors to the configure services method:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

and then in the Configure method

```html
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

if use web api you can use this code :

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
    return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
}
```